# How to get most common words with a specific value in a dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with score points 0 and 1 and corresponding reviews, I want to find the most common words in reviews with 0 points and 1 points. I tried this but it gives the count of all words:

```
count = defaultdict(int)
l = df['Summary']
for number in l:
    count[number] += 1

print(count)
```

How can I find the most common values from all the rows with 1 score and 0 score?

Comment: how does your `review` column look like? What is your desired output?

Comment: review column has text in it and each text is labeled as 0 or 1.I am looking for the most common words in all the rows labeled as 1. for example every row with 1 score has 'good' in it and I want find that word.

Comment: I am not able to understand the part that text is labeled as 0 or 1. if you could show the sample dataset, then it would be more clear.

Comment: like this: df['Summary'] = [good and great, good, bad] and df['Score']=[1,1,0]. So every review has a point like a rating. Good and great rated with a '1' etc. So I am looking for what is the most common word with the reviews which has 1 score.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a frequency dict. If your columns can be viewed as a list of lists:

```
data = [[0, "text samle 1"], [0, "text sample 2"], [1, "text sample 3"]]
```

...then you can:

```
fd0 = dict()
fd1 = dict()
for list_item in data:
    associated_value = list_item[0]

    #note the split(' ') splits the string into a list of words
    for word in list_item[1].split(' '):
        if associated_value == 0:
            fd0[word] = 1 if word not in fd0 else fd0[word] + 1
        elif associated_value == 1:
            fd1[word] = 1 if word not in fd1 else fd1[word] + 1
```

At the end of the loop your fd0 should have frequency for label 0 and fd1 should have frequency for label 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this

```
            review  score
0       bad review      0
1      good review      1
2  very bad review      0
3   movie was good      1
```

You could do something like

```
words = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['score'], row['review'].split(' '))              
    for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()
words.columns = ['word', 'score']
print(words.groupby(['score', 'word']).size())
```

which gives you

```
score  word
0      bad       2
       review    2
       very      1
1      good      2
       movie     1
       review    1
       was       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting this error in line 2: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: ok you must have some empty reviews in the dataframe (np.nan). If you fill the empty values with df['review'] = df['review'].fillna('') before running the code above, it should work alright.

Answer (score 0):

```
most_common_0 = ''
most_common_1 = ''

for text, score in zip(df['Summary'], df['Score']):
    if score == 1:
        most_common_1 += ' ' + text
    else:
        most_common_0 += ' ' + text

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(most_common_1.split())
print(c.most_common(2)) # change this 2 to the number you want to analyze
```

Output

```
[('good', 2), ('and', 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks foor the reply, I tried it but it gave an error: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str, so Imade df['Summary'].str but now it gave an error like this: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: change to `most_common_1 += ' ' + str(text)` , same for 0.